# Synchronizing process execution in a cluster with 2 nodes in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, hazelcast

I have a cluster with 2 nodes and a shared file system. Each of these nodes runs has a java process that runs periodically. That process accesses the file system and handles some files and after the processing it deletes those files.
The problem here is that only one of the schedules processes should access the files. The other process should, if the first process runs, skip the execution.

- My first attempt to solve this issue to create a hidden file `.lock`
  . When the first process starts the execution it should move the file
  into another folder and start handling files. When the other
  scheduled process starts the execution it first checks if the `.lock`
  file is present and if it isn't the process skips the execution. 
  When the first process finishes the execution it moves the `.lock`
  file back to its original folder.   I was using the [Files.move()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)
  method with `ATOMIC_MOVE` option but after a certain amount of time I
  got unexpected behaviour.
- My second attempt was to use a distributed lock like `Hazelcast`. I did some tests and it seems ok but this solution seems a bit complicated for a task that is this simple.

My question is: Is there any other smarter/simpler solution for this problem or my only option is to use `Hazelcast`? How would you solve this issue?